# Accessing CollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have added a button on the `collectionviewcell`, and once user clicks on that button, it calls the following method, but `uviCollectionViewCell` is returning nil.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(collectionView == productCollectionView)
    {
        __weak ProductCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        cell.addBtnOutlet.tag = indexPath.row;
        [cell.addBtnOutlet addTarget:self
                        action:@selector(collectionViewCellAddButtonPressed:)
              forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }
  return cell;
}

- (IBAction)collectionViewCellAddButtonPressed:(UIButton *)button{
     NSLog(@"Add Button Clicked" );
     // the following is nil
     UICollectionViewCell *uviCollectionCell =  [self.productCollectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndex:0]];
 }
```

Comment: [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow: button.tag inSection:0], for full code `[self.productCollectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow: button.tag inSection:0]];`

Comment: @anbu-karthik : Thanks for editing the answer I have kept your edit while am not sure what OP's requirement is hence kept a note as welll

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik, thanks a lot it worked. I did not add the section, I thought if I dont set it up, then it will assign zero as default. Please put your code as an answer and I am going to accept it.

Comment: @SandeepBhandari - its ok my bro,

Comment: @hotspring - check sandeepbhandari answer also same, accpt that answer

Comment: ok, I have accepted sandeepbhandari as answer. Thanks for being generous and giving credits to others :-)

Comment: @anbu-karthik : Thank u :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is,

If you need a cell with index path being equal to button tag then as Karthik said,

```
UICollectionViewCell *uviCollectionCell = [self.collectionView.dataSource collectionView:self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:button.tag inSection:0]];
```

if you need always a cell at index path 0,0 then use

```
UICollectionViewCell *uviCollectionCell = [self.collectionView.dataSource collectionView:self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do without tag then

```
- (IBAction)collectionViewCellAddButtonPressed:(UIButton *)button{
    NSLog(@"Add Button Clicked" );
    UICollectionViewCell *uviCollectionCell =  (UICollectionViewCell *)button.superview;

    // if this is return nil then use like below as i am not sure it will retuen contentview for superview
    UICollectionViewCell *uviCollectionCell1 =  (UICollectionViewCell *)button.superview.superview;
 }
```